# Android Fragment not showing after coming back after a while?

Tags: android, fragment, lifecycle

I have a sherlock activity(A) that contains a fragment(B) which again contains a tab and FragmentViewPager(C) which contains a Fragment (D).
I have a weird issue here.

Initially everything shows up fine.

If I close the app by pressing the home button, then come back immediately to the app, then everything is fine (A containing B containing C containing D)

However, if I close the app by pressing the home button, then work on other apps for a long time, then come back to my app, then I see A containing B containing C containing an empty screen.

Here are two questions.
1. Why doesn't the fragment D show up? 
2. It seems like something is wrong with onResume() or something in D? Or is it related to process issue? Lifecycle? How can I fix that?
3. In order to recreate the issue, I have to close the app, then spend a lot of time playing other apps. Is there a way to recreate this issue quickly without having to waste time?

Thanks a lot...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by containing fragments within fragments? Do you want to implement ViewPager???

Comment: did you ever resolve this?